# C# property sheet

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm new to C#. I want to make a property sheet - something like the ones used for controls properties from Visual Studio. Is there any class that holds this type of information or I must create my class using static texts and edit boxes? I want something simple like:

Tag1 Value1

Tag1 Value1

Tag1 Value1

...

where Value may be of different type(probably I will use string and parse them later)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In WinForms, you can use the [`PropertyGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx) control. It is exactly like the property view in Visual Studio. The article I linked to explains how to use it.